# TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/8.5

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I got an issue with the tfs.

Firstly after my tfs server database got full.

So in order to solve it i cleared the table of logs from tfs server.

Now at time of clearing data one of my workspace had checkout of one file. As soon i finished my clearing data, it is giving me this error `TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/8.5.` at every time i try to get latest version.

Thats how i am unable to take latest.

Any help would be appritiable.

Comment: Login the TFS AT machine to perform get latest, would you get the same error?

Answer (score 48):

1. Right-click solution
2. `Get Latest Version`
3. Try commit again

Issue started for me when I upgraded to VS2017

Comment: For me, this didn't work. I had to open the Source Control Explorer from the home screen, then perform the checkin again without problems. (happened several times)

Comment: Interestingly, even the 'Get Latest Version' on the solution did not overwrite my edits (ie work in progress was preserved) and the check in worked afterwards.

Comment: `Get Lastest Version` shouldn't overwrite edits, if it finds a conflict it should offer you the option to resolve conflicts

Comment: Get Latest Version didn't work for me.  Restarting Visual Studio seemed to clear up the problem, though.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Odd... this entire issue started with changes to app.config not being reflected in the .cs no matter what I tried (including deleting the obj and bin folders). Once I was finally able to get the changes to reflect (via complete delete / reload of the TFS directory), this issue occurred.

Answer (score 36):

For me it helps if i just click the Refresh button at the top of the Team Explorer.
After that, the message disappears and i can normally check in.

Comment: Nice. Worked for me!

Comment: Yup. Simple and to the point. Still wonder what's going on under the hood though. Plüs 1.

Answer (score 30):

For me, it helped just to restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

1. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache.
2. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data
3. After cleaned, on Server machine, click Start and select Run… to open the dialog box, then input **iisreset.exe** and click OK, wait it run completely.

Answer (score 1):

I just reconnected to the team project in the Team Explorer and my commit went through, didn't have to restart anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When I closed an open Source Control Explorer window and all the files in Visual Studio, I was able to check in.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got solution, exactly got that how to do.

Do checkout that file and check in an old version of that file

and

than do take latest.

It will not generate this error again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a copy of the file that is on TFS you can add it as a new file to TFS, and then do get latest version of the file, and then select keep local when you get the conflict error, and then you can check in the file. After that you can then get latest with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Run as Administrator from Visual, It will never make this error again.

Answer (score 0):

- **1 : Open TFS window.**
- **2 : Click on Refresh(F5).**
- **3: Try again to Check-in.**

[CLick here see Solution (Image):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfb4P.png)

I have faced same issue while check-in on TFS : You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with the latest update installed v15.2 (26430.4) on Windows 10 64-bit. The issue has been happening for awhile, it is not new with the latest VS update. We're using a TFS repository hosted on Visual Studio Online, i.e. our TFS repository is at COMPANY.visualstudio.com.

Frequently, when checking in, or attempting to shelve changes from the Team Explorer window in VS, I'll get an error message indicating I'm not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/10.0. I've had reports of other developers experiencing this as well.

We've discovered the following workarounds.

Clicking the refresh button on the top of the Team Explorer window and then trying the operation again

If you have multiple workspaces, changing to a different one, then back to the original, then trying the operation again

It appears something is "stale" perhaps with the TFS connection and that refreshing it prevents the error message.

Hitting the refresh button over the Team explorer, resolved the issue.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55789/you-are-not-authorized-to-access-microsoft-iis100.html                                                    The above link has all the information for the issue reported for IIS 10.0 as well

Answer (score 0):

I had a locked item. When I excluded/undo the locked item it went through.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh TFS not worked for me

In my case the error disappear restarting Visual Studio

or me, it helped just to restart Visual Studio.